# Hashmap using tuple as key

Tags: java

What I would like to do is create a hashmap that uses a tuple as a key. What I have done so far:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> seen = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

and for the key I use `(X+"#"+Y)` with X, Y being integers. So, when I have two integers I just need to search for this string. However, for very large and many X and Y creating large strings instead of a tuple of integers eats up a lot of memory. How could this be done using `(X, Y)` and not `(X+"#"+Y)`?

Comment: You would create your own class that holds 2 ints and overrides equals and hashCode, using the 2 ints in the equals and hashCode methods, or you could use a similar existing class, such as `java.util.Point` -- but (and this is a big but), not sure if this will be more memory efficient than using a String.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If X and Y are up to 500000 wouldn't (500000,500000) need a lot less memory than "500000#500000"?

Comment: Are there multiple Y's per X value? (or multiple X's per Y value)

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own class called Tuple that overrides Java's hashCode() function (I assume Java's default implementation won't work for this so you'll have to make your own), which you could then use as the key to your Hashmap :)

EDIT: As many people have already mentioned, I forgot to override equals() as well. Here is the implementation including the equals() function.

Something like this should do:

```
class Tuple {
  public Tuple(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 17;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.y;
    return hash;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (this.getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;
    Tuple that = (Tuple) other;
    return (this.x == that.x) && (this.y == that.y);
  }

  private int x;
  private int y;
}
```

Though as previously mentioned, you could just use Java's java.awt.Point :)

Comment: Not only the hashCode(), you need to override the equals() as well.

Comment: Indeed -- overriding equals correctly is absolutely *essential* here

Comment: And no, you would not want to use `Point2D` as that holds 2 double values, not 2 int values. You would want to use `java.awt.Point` instead.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My bad - I always confuse the two. I fixed my response above - thank you for letting me know!

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to use `java.awt.Point` either, because it inherits `hashCode()` from `Point2D` which calculates the hash code in terms of `double` values. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own pair class which is probably the preferred way to go about this, but javax.util also has its own Pair class but the implementation is quite sparse so i usually avoid it.

If you do chose to write your own pair class, you must override Object’s hashcode and equals methods